# use of parametric ndsolve with a constraint

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, constraint

I want to solve differential equation
$$ \frac{y''[x]}{(1+y'[x]y'[x])^{3/2}} = -a -y[x]/ \sqrt{2} + x/ \sqrt{2} $$ subject to boundary condition $y(-1) = y(1) = 0$ for some value of $a$. $a$ is found from the condition $\int^{1}_{-1} y[x]\mathrm{d}x = M $ for a given $M$.

This equation arises when one needs to find the shape of  a drop resting on a solid surface under gravity.

To start with numerical solution with NDSolve for a fixed value $a$ works fine.

```
   asymSolNumGrav = 
     NDSolve[{yG''[x]/((1 + yG'[x] yG'[x]))^(3/2) == -2921/10000 - 
         yG[x]/Sqrt[2] + x /Sqrt[2], yG[-1] == 1/10000, yG[1] == 1/1000}, 
      yG[x], {x, -1, 1}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 20]
    Plot[yG[x] /. asymSolNumGrav, {x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
    NIntegrate[yG[x] /. asymSolNumGrav[[1]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

this gives

[image]

Next, I tried to find $a$ given the integral constraint with parametric NDSolve as follows along the lines given in another thread [Constraint of NDSolve with an integral of the solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209125/constraint-of-ndsolve-with-an-integral-of-the-solution)

```
paraNDsol = 
     ParametricNDSolveValue[{yP''[x]/((1 + yP'[x] yP'[x]))^(3/2) == -a - 
         yP[x]/Sqrt[2] + x /Sqrt[2], yP[-1] == 1/1000, yP[1] == 1/1000}, 
      yP, {x, -1, 1}, {a}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 20] 


M[a_?NumericQ] := (NIntegrate[paraNDsol[a][x], {x, -1, 1}] - 0.2)^2
sol1 = NMinimize[{M[a], 1/10 < a < 99/100}, a]
{Plot[Evaluate[Table[paraNDsol[a][x], {a, 0.1, 1, .1}]], {x, -1, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
 Plot[paraNDsol[a][x] /. Last[sol1], {x, -1, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]}
```

This gives error

```
 ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz
    NIntegrate::inumr
```

How can I get a smooth numerical solution with ParametricNDSolveValue in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Mathematica cannot integrate the ODE all the way from -1 to 1 for certain values of $a$.  The important error messages that are returned are

> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At x$8411 == -0.760075, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

> NMinimize::nnum: The function value (-0.2+NIntegrate[paraNDsol[0.747922][x],{x,-1,1}])^2 is not a number at {a} = {0.747922}.

What's happening here `NIntegrate` is trying to sample `M` at various points, including for $a = 0.747922$.  It calls `ParametricNDSolve`, which tries to solve the ODE with this $a$ value and fails, generating the first error and returning a non-numerical answer.  `NIntegrate` then complains that it didn't get a numerical answer.

Thankfully, one can still look at the behavior of `M` and figure out where the minimum actually is:

```
Plot[M[a], {a, 0.1, 0.99}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

(The options are there to make this code run in a reasonable amount of time.)  It appears the function reaches zero between 0.1 and 0.3, so we can search just in this range and avoid the trouble spots:

```
sol1 = NMinimize[{M[a], 1/10 < a < 3/10}, a]

(* {1.69381*10^-21, {a -> 0.19603}} *)

Plot[paraNDsol[a][x] /. sol1[[2]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

---

What's a bit troubling about this example is that `ParametricNDSolve` will happily return solutions for which the boundary conditions are not satisfied, without giving any warnings (MM 12.3.1, Mac OSX ARM):

```
Plot[paraNDsol[0.9][x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I would therefore advise caution in using this "graph" technique without actually plotting out your results and making sure that they're doing what you want them to.